# Write a JavaScript program to check a number from three given numbers in an array where two numbers are equal, find the third one

Tags: javascript

```js
function findThird1() {
    let n1 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[0].value);
    let n2 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[1].value);
    let n3 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[2].value);
    document.getElementById('findThirdResult').innerHTML = findThird2([n1, n2, n3]);
  }
  function findThird2(arr) {
    let two = [];
    let one = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])  {
          two.push(arr[i]);      
        }
        if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
          one.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    if ((two.length == 2) && (one.length == 1)) {
      return 'The two equals: ' + two + '<br>' + 'The third: ' + one;
    } else {
      return 'Not equals.'
    }  
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="3">
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="3">
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="4">
<button onclick="findThird1()">Try</button>
<div id="findThirdResult"></div>
```

I wrote the code above to solve the problem but it does not work. I loop through every item in the array to find two equals and one unequal but it has some errors.

Comment: Try debugging your code (using `console.log` for example). You'll find your mistake *very* easily

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now you've told us what you want the code to do (good), and you've given us runnable code (good), and you've told us you have some errors (good). But you've not told us what those errors are (bad), and what does not work (bad).

Comment: See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I have not run your code but if you push when arr[i] != arr[j] then there is high probability that you push twice since if a==b != c, you would push for a!=c AND also for b!=c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findThird2(arr) {
let one = [];
let two = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
    let isOne = true;
    for (var j = i + 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
            two.push(arr[i]);
            isOne = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isOne && two.indexOf(arr[i]) < 0) {
        one.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
if (two.length == 1) {
    return 'The two equals: ' + two[0] + '<br>' + 'The third: ' + one[0];
} else {
    return 'Not equals.';
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

*I think you are trying relatively in a complicated way.*

You can try with some built-in functions like `map()` and `filter()`. Also, you should not return the *htmlString* from the function, you can directly set that to the element's `innerHTML`.

Try the following way:

```js
function findThird1() {
  let resultEl = document.getElementById('findThirdResult');
  let all = document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput');
  //get all the values
  let allValues = Array.from(all).map(el => el.value);
  //get the duplicates
  var two = allValues.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i);
  //get the other value
  var one = allValues.filter(i => !two.includes(i));
  if (two.length && one.length) {
    resultEl.innerHTML =  'The two equals: ' + two + '<br>' + 'The third: ' + one;
  } else {
    resultEl.innerHTML = 'Not equals.'
  }  
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="3">
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="3">
<input type="number" class="findThirdInput" value="4">
<button onclick="findThird1()">Try</button>
<div id="findThirdResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this is a good way to solve the problem, but i want to know where I make mistakes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this

```
function findThird1() {
  let n1 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[0].value);
  let n2 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[1].value);
  let n3 = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('.findThirdInput')[2].value);
  document.getElementById('findThirdResult').innerHTML = findThird2([n1, n2, n3]);
}

function findThird2(arr) {
  let flag = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i + 1]) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return flag ? 'Equals' : 'not equals'
}
```